# WebService method takes too long sometimes

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf, monitoring, administration

I'm a junior Asp.net developer and got an interesting task. I'm hosting a Web Service. When Client calls a method which saves some data to our database it takes sometimes to long time to succeed. Usually **~5 sec** sometimes **30+sec**. I don't really know where to start.

To me it seems that, it can be caused by `2 reasons`:

1. Client has bad internet connection.
2. My database is overloaded

But how can I prove that or find the actual cause?

Comment: or (3) possibly parameter sniffing

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx

Comment: On what operating system are you hosting your web service? Windows Server 2008?

Comment: yes Windows Server 2008 @Regfor

Answer (score 0):

Run a WCF trace and a database trace. Between the two of them you should be able to find out if it's one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try [profiling on SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx) side to check query executions. Also you can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on server to see what requests are coming to it and what hapens to them over some time. Check the code of the service for loops(may be there is some recursive check that checks some parameter, if that parameter is not the value expected- freeze and check again).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to debug into the web service code as the client is hitting it.

If it takes a long time to hit the debug point then the client has a problem.

If it hits the debug quickly then step through the code and see which step is taking a long time.

Answer (score 0):

When speaking about deploying and hosting into/on Windows Servers higher then 2003, there is possibility to install AppFabric, which has great features for monitoring and troubleshooting web services and web applications on IIS.

Monitoring could be configured through UI in IIS Management and also through web.config. And is better then default IIS tracing capabilities.

How to achieve it and what I mean is better described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677277.aspx

Also there is ability to use AppFabric Distributed caching, when database is especially overloaded with read operations.

Check first how long are your requests executing. And then decide profile or not database. Try to design your architecture in that way to avoid blocking after save, maybe async response, or client not always should wait when saving is completed. Client can later ask saving status and you will be not blocking him. Anyway to know exact, more detail either about architecture, or about requirements needed.